# Origin of ‘for shame’

Tags: phrases, phrase-origin

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/for-shame):

> you should feel ashamed

Why does ‘for shame’ mean that? ‘Shame’ there is easily understandable, but I can’t understand why ‘for’ is used there for that function. Did it originate in a longer phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably from [forshame](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/forshame#:%7E:text=From%20Middle%20English%20forshamen%2C%20from,to%20for%2D%20%2B%E2%80%8E%20shame.):

> From Middle English forshamen, from Old English forscamian (“to make ashamed, be ashamed, be modest”); equivalent to for- +‎ shame.

(Wiktionary)

the expression "for shame" dates back to the 14th century  as suggested by [Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/for--shame)

Comment: I suppose this makes the most sense. I dithered over accepting/upvoting this, because how would it (whether in an imperative sense or not) change from something with an object (‘forshame yourself!’ or ‘that forshames you!’ or something; obviously not correct in the 14th century, but you get my point) to just the word, but I guess it’s analogous to the german ‘danke’ coming from ‘ich danke dir/Ihnen/euch’.